# Java Download Manager with dialog save file

Tags: java, dialog, download, save

Sorry if my question is bad or repeat,
in https://github.com/luugiathuy/Java-Download-Manager i cannot found variabel to setting detination folder, and how to add a dialog to save file to local directory/destination
sorry my english is bad

Comment: How about calling this method `public Downloader createDownload(URL verifiedURL, String outputFolder)`?

Comment: Sory once again. Then, how to create the file name is my definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to achieve your requirement:

`public Downloader createDownload(URL verifiedURL, String outputFolder)`

So your code would have something like this:

`Downloader.getInstance().createDownload([url],[folder_location_path])`

Comment: then how to set the filename with my definition, not filename from server ?

Answer (score 0):

As @Sujay pointed out, why don't you call the method `public Downloader createDownload(URL verifiedURL, String outputFolder)`? That should solve your problem.